# What is a I♭ chord?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions

I was watching Music Matters' video on counterpoint when I came across this chord progression:

| I V | I V IV | II♭ V I VI I♭ | II♭ V I ||

My question is what is a I♭ chord. Is this chord common? Is this correct notation (vs VII)? Does it have a name (like the neapolitan chord after it)? Does it have a conventional use?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 22):

I think, based on the co.uk domain, and the instructor's accent, that those are not flat signs, but British inversion signs.

> a = root position
>
> b = first inversion
>
> c = second inversion

I'm also assume the system used doesn't change letter case for major/minor qualities.

So, it means `| ii6/3 V I vi I6/3 | ii6/3 ...` in the system that I'm familiar with.

https://offtonic.com/theory/book/6-3.html

Comment: So it's neither b or ♭ but 6?

Comment: This is exactly what the instructor says (_"two bee, or two in first inversion"_) if you [watch the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNOTsKmuKrE) for about a minute and a half.

Comment: @user1079505, in that system it is a letter, lower case "b". If you use Arabic numerals, like in figured bass, it would be a `6/3` or for short just `6`. All of them meaning a first inversion chord.